# after partitioning, mounting and turning of, directory is missing

Tags: mount, directory

Recently, I have partitioned and mounted the second disk of my Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) as */hdd*. I added a directory (called *DCUA*) and some files to *hdd*. After turning off and turning on */hdd* is there but the directory and the files are missing. *locate* finds *DCUA* but *find* does not (*cd* is also not possible). Nothing is stored in *lost+found* ?

Is there anything I can do to recover the data ?

Comment: Is the hard disk mounted? Running `mount` in a terminal should show a line concerning `/hdd`.

Comment: `mount` shows `/dev/sdb1 on /hdd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Comment: What happens if you unmount `/hdd`? Can you see the data then?

Comment: yes, now I can see the data. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, it was determined that `/hdd` really was mounted, and that unmounting it revealed the missing data.

This means that when `/hdd/DCUA` was created and files copied to it, `/hdd` itself wasn’t mounted, so the directory was created on the containing file system (presumably `/`). Another possibility is that the shell used to create `DCUA` and the files inside it was already in `/hdd` before the latter was mounted, so its current directory remained in the old `/hdd` (on `/`).

To fix that, with `/hdd` unmounted, rename `/hdd` and re-create it:

```
mv /hdd /hdd.old
mkdir /hdd
```

then mount it:

```
mount /hdd
```

You will then be able to copy or move data from `/hdd.old/DCUA` to `/hdd`.